# Problemas con nombre de archivo Android

Tags: android, android-studio

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Hice una aplicación en `Android Studio` donde mediante un `EditText` el usuario ingresa el nombre del archivo que quiere enviar a través de un `socket`.

El problema no es el `socket`, el problema es que cuando uso el `string` que ingreso el usuario para buscar el archivo y enviarlo me sale un error del tipo:

> **/storage/emulated/0/Download/[Ljava.lang.String;@3df5024: open failed: ENOENT(No such file or diretory)**

El código es:

```
java
button.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (editText1.getText().toString().length()>0)
                        {
                            Cliente cl = new Cliente();

                            String nombre = editText1.getText().toString();
                            cl.execute(nombre);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Ingrese nombre de archivo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
```

Y para buscar el archivo hago

```
java
protected String doInBackground(String... strings){

            File archivo;
            String ruta_archivo = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
            String nombre = strings.toString();
            try {

                archivo = new File(ruta_archivo+"/"+nombre);
```

Cuando pongo la ruta manualmente, por ejemplo **archivo = new File(ruta_archivo+"/ejemplo.txt");** el archivo se envía sin problemas.

Espero puedan orientarme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el método `doInBackground()` recibe un parámetro **varargs**. Los parámetros varargs funcionan como array. Al obtener el toString() del parametro, obtiene el toString() de un array no de un String.

Para solucionar el problema solo tienes que obtener el String que contiene el parámetro varargs en la posición cero. Por ejemplo:

```
String nombre = strings[0];
```

---

Un método con un parámetro varargs puede recibir una cantidad indeterminada de argumentos. Para acceder a estos argumentos utilizas un indice en el párametro varargs, como si fuera un array.

```
public void metodo(String... textos) {

    System.out.println(textos[0])
    System.out.println(textos[1])
    System.out.println(textos[2])
}

metodo("Hola", "Mundo", "!");

// Imprime:
//
// Hola
// Mundo
// !
```

Comment: Me salvaste la vida! Muchas gracias, funciono de maravilla :3

Answer (score 0):

Puede que el error sea el nombre del archivo, podrías intentar imprimir el nombre de tu variable `String nombre = strings.toString();` para observar que valor tiene, te darás cuenta que la variables `strings` es una array, depende de como estés mandando tus variables deberas obtener el indice correcto. Verifica que este nombre sea correcto y no sea `null`. Por otro lado también están los **permiso**s que tienes que tener en cuenta cuando deseas acceder a otras carpetas fuera de tu aplicación.

Comment: Mil gracias! Ya funciona perfecto

Answer (score 0):

```
String... strings //significa que puede recibir un array de String
```

Por lo que para recibir el nombre que deseas debes hacerlo extrayendo lo que viene en la primera posicion de ese array:

```
String nombre = strings[0];
```

Ademas te recomiendo validar si la caja de texto esta vacia:

```
  if (!editText1.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){

   }
```

Usa el metodo `trim()` para eliminar los espacios en blanco al inicil y al final ya que si un usuario escribe un espacio en tu validacion actual dara verdadero pero en realidad no habra texto.

Lo mismo para obtener el texto:

```
String nombre = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me salvaste :3